# Storing table data as blob in column in different table(Oracle)

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql, blob

Requirement : We have around 500 tables from which around 10k rows in each tables are of interest. We want to store this data as blob in a table. All data when exported to a file is of 250 MB. Now one option is to store this 250 MB file in a blob (Oracle allows 4 GB) or store each table data as blob in a blob column i.e we will have one row for each table and blob column will have that table data.

Now with respect to performance, which option is better in terms of performance. Also this data needs to be fetched and insert into database.

Basically, this will be delivered to customer and our utility will read the data from blob and will insert into database.

Questions:

1) How to insert table data as blob in blob column
2) How to read from that blob column and then prepare insert statements.
3) Is there any benefit we can get from compression of table which contains blob data. If yes, then for reading how to uncompress that.
4) Does this approach will work on MSSQL and DB2 also.
What are the other considerations while designing tables having blob.
Please suggest

Comment: What is your actual business requirement? Why must the table data be stored in a series of BLOBs instead of how they're actually stored now?

I've never seen a design like what you describe as wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I have impression you want to go from structured content to non-structured. 
I hope you know what you are trading off, but I do not have that impression reading your question. 
Going BLOB you lose relationship / constraints between values. 
It could be faster to read one block of data, but when you need to write minor change, you may need to write bigger "chunk" in case of big BLOBs.

To insert BLOB in database you can use any available API (OCI, JDBC. Even pl/sql if you access it only on server side).

For compression, you can use BLOB option. Also, you can DIY using some library (if you need to think about other RDBMS types).

Comment: @Wernfried , igr Main Intention is to have this set of data in seperate tables as this will be used only one off case. Keeping the data in same tables will impact the performance of all users as this data is used only once when upgrading from one version to another. If we deliver the data in same table, it will lie there unused, We cannot delete that also as it may required in the future. Its an OLTP environment and doubling the rows for each tables is not recommended so the idea is to keep in seperate compressed blob  format and use only when required.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to store a table into a BLOB? For archive or transfer you could export the tables using `exp` or perferablyl `expdp`. These files you can compress and transfer or store as BLOB inside another Oracle database.

Max. size of LOB was 4 GB till Oracle release 9 as far as I remember. Today the limit is 8 TB to 128 TB, depending on your DB-Block Size.